# OCamlのパッケージが上手くインストール出来ません。

Tags: debian, ocaml

環境は以下のとおりです。

`Linux kali 3.7-trunk-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.7.2-0+kali5 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

以下のようにインストールしようとすると、

```
 sudo apt-get -f install  ocaml-findlib camlidl libcamomile-ocaml-dev  camlp4-extra libgmp3-dev
```

---

以下のようなエラーが出力されます。

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... DoneSome packages could not be installed. This  may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   camlidl : Depends: ocaml-nox-3.12.1
   libcamomile-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-nox-3.12.1
   ocaml-findlib : Depends: libfindlib-ocaml but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: libfindlib-ocaml-dev but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

よって、以下のようにすると、

```
   %wget http://www.rpmseek.com/download/http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/ocaml/ocaml-base-nox_3.12.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   %dpkg -i ocaml-base-nox_3.12.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

---

このようにエラーが出力されます。

```
%dpkg -i ocaml-base-nox_3.12.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
dpkg: warning: downgrading ocaml-base-nox from 4.02.1-1ppa3~precise to 3.12.1-4ubuntu1
(Reading database ... 260430 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace ocaml-base-nox 4.02.1-1ppa3~precise (using ocaml-base-nox_3.12.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement ocaml-base-nox ...
Replaced by files in installed package ocaml-compiler-libs ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ocaml-base-nox:
 ocaml-base-nox depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.13-38+deb7u6.
 ocaml-compiler-libs (4.02.1-1ppa3~precise) breaks ocaml-base-nox (<< 4) and is installed.
  Version of ocaml-base-nox to be configured is 3.12.1-4ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing ocaml-base-nox (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ocaml-base-nox
```

---

ちなみに、ocaml-base-noxは入っています。

```
%apt-get install ocaml-base-nox                                                                 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ocaml-base-nox is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
```

---

libfindlib-ocaml-devが入っていないということで、

```
%apt-get install libfindlib-ocaml-dev
```

---

やはり、インストールができません。

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfindlib-ocaml-dev : Depends: libfindlib-ocaml-8p7u5
                        Depends: ocaml-nox-3.12.1
                        Recommends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
```

---

では、次こちらをインストールしようとすると、

```
%apt-get install libfindlib-ocaml-8p7u5
```

---

やはりエラーが帰ってきます。

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libfindlib-ocaml' instead of 'libfindlib-ocaml-8p7u5'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfindlib-ocaml : Depends: ocaml-base-nox-3.12.1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

ocaml-base-nox-3.12.1をインストールすることが出来れば、他のパッケージもインストールできそうなのですが、ocaml-base-nox-3.12.1自体がインストール出来ないのでどのようにしたら良いか教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ocaml-base-nox:
ocaml-base-nox depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
 Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.13-38+deb7u6.
ocaml-compiler-libs (4.02.1-1ppa3~precise) breaks ocaml-base-nox (<< 4) and is installed.
 Version of ocaml-base-nox to be configured is 3.12.1-4ubuntu1.
```

そんなに深刻ではない、単純な依存関係の問題のように見えます。まず、 `libc6` をバージョン `2.15` 以上に上げること、そうしたら、既にインストールしてあるだろう、 `ocaml-compiler-libs` をアンインストールしてください。その後、 `apt-get upgrade` でシステムをできるだけ最新にしてから再度トライです。